# My CSS file doesn't load when printing from the browser

Tags: html, css, file, printing, extern

I created a page, when I wanted to print it, I noticed that it is completely different from what I did, it like my CSS file is not loaded when I try to Print it.

My CSS file is an extern file, the `<link...>` code line is created in another page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the link to the stylesheet in the header is correct (media="all").

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/link/to/.css" media="all">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your file has loaded or not using Inspect .
On **Chrome**

*Right click page > Inspect 
In the new window, click Sources tab. In the left pane, you can see list of files loaded.* 
Correct way to include a css file is :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file.css">
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: i didn't find the file, this is my link code :

 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo url('cssnomin'); ?>site/index_imp"  />`

Comment: is it a php file?

Comment: @Meryem if the file isn't shown there,it means that it isn't getiing included. This is your error.If my answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: thanks, i know that it's not included, but i want to know why and how to includ when i want ti print, because i can see it without print

Comment: I'm not into php, so I cannot help u there .